# Sorting Highest to Lowest using a loop and arrays

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

```
while Checked == False:
for Counter in range(1, NoOfRecords + 1):
    if Test[Counter] < Test[Counter + 1]:
        Temp = Test[Counter]
        Test[Counter] = Test[Counter + 1]
        Test[Counter + 1] = Temp
    if Test[1] > Test[2] > Test[3] > Test[3] > Test[4] > Test[5]:
        Checked = True
print(Test[1], Test[2], Test[3], Test[4], Test[5])
```

My aim is to, basically, sort inputs from the lowest to the highest. Before this, the user is asked to input 5 numbers between 0 to 5.

However, after the 5 inputs have been inputed, nothing else comes up, no print.

Can you suggest an improvement? or a different type of loop for the sorting process? Thanks

**EDIT** Full code Below

```
import array
Test = array.array ("f", range(11))
Counter = int(1)
NoOfRecords = int(5)
Checked = False
Temp = int(0)
def Tempurature (Day,Lowest,Highest):
    ok = False
    while ok == False:
        try:
            Input = float(input(Day + " Tempurature:"))
            if Input >= Lowest and Input <= Highest:
                ok = True
                return Input
            else:
                print ("\nPlease enter a number between " + str(Lowest) + " and " + str(Highest))
        except:
            print ("\nPlease enter a valid number")

for Counter in range(1, NoOfRecords + 1):
    Test[Counter] = Tempurature ("Mid-Day", 0, 5)

while Checked == False:
    for Counter in range(1, NoOfRecords + 1):
        if Test[Counter] < Test[Counter + 1]:
            Temp = Test[Counter]
            Test[Counter] = Test[Counter + 1]
            Test[Counter + 1] = Temp
    if Test[1] > Test[2] > Test[3] > Test[3] > Test[4] > Test[5]:
        Checked = True

print(Test[1], Test[2], Test[3], Test[4], Test[5])
```

Comment: what about `Test = sorted(Test)`? (assuming there are `int`s in your list; you'd have to convert the strings to `int` first if you fill the list with user input).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on the sorting procedure used, I would suggest to modify it as follows:

```
while Checked == False:
    for Counter in range(1, NoOfRecords):
        if Test[Counter] < Test[Counter + 1]:
            Temp = Test[Counter]
            Test[Counter] = Test[Counter + 1]
            Test[Counter + 1] = Temp
    if Test[1] >= Test[2] and Test[2] >= Test[3] and Test[2] >= Test[3] and Test[3] >= Test[4] and Test[4] >= Test[5]:
        Checked = True
```

This is because you want to focus only on the part of the array being sorted, therefore `for Counter in range(1, NoOfRecords)` (the last element is taken into account since you reference `Test[Counter + 1]` inside the `for` loop).

Also, one should test for possible equality in the `if` condition to avoid the situation that the program would get stuck inside the `while` loop

Comment: This really helped me, however would there be a way to make the final check a little shorter? The `if Test[1] >= Test[2]`

Comment: sure, one could either chain the comparisons, i.e., `if Test[1] >= Test[2] >= Test[3] >= Test[4] >= Test[5]` or use something like this `if all([Test[i] >= Test[i + 1] for i in range(1, 5)])` since `all` returns `True` iff all conditions are satisfied

Answer (score 1):

Edit: My answer was wrong, the order-check is not backwards, so I've rewritten.

This time, see this:

```
if Test[1] > Test[2] > Test[3] > Test[3] > Test[4] > Test[5]:
```

Whoa, whoa:

```
                       Test[3] > Test[3]
```

Can't ever happen.

Let's also `print(Test)` for one run:

```
Mid-Day Tempurature: 1
Mid-Day Tempurature: 2
Mid-Day Tempurature: 3
Mid-Day Tempurature: 4
Mid-Day Tempurature: 5
array('f', [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0])
array('f', [0.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 1.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0])
array('f', [0.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 1.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0])
array('f', [0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 2.0, 1.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0])
array('f', [0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 2.0, 1.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0])
array('f', [0.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0])
array('f', [0.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0])
array('f', [0.0, 5.0, 6.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0])
array('f', [0.0, 5.0, 6.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0])
array('f', [0.0, 6.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0])
6.0 5.0 4.0 3.0 2.0
```

See the sorting loop reaches for Test[5+1] it reaches out into the element you never typed and drags 6.0 to the front of the list.

But you say "*My aim is to, basically, sort inputs from the lowest to the highest.*" and this shows you're sorting them highest to lowest.

1. Why are you using an 11 element array to act as a 5 element list?
2. No need for `int(0)`, `int(5)`, 0 and 5 are already ints. And you don't need to pre-write every variable at the top, only some.
3. The `while ok == false` check when getting numbers doesn't do anything useful, since you return the function from the middle of the while loop.
4. Swap the comparisons to make them sort lowest to highest.
5. Add <= to the tests so it works for equal numbers as well
6. `While Checked == False:` is more idiomatic as `While not Checked:`

So:

```
import array
Test = array.array ("f", range(11))
NoOfRecords = 5
Checked = False

def Temperature (Day,Lowest,Highest):
    while True:
        try:
            Input = float(input(Day + " Temperature:"))
            if Input >= Lowest and Input <= Highest:
                return Input
            else:
                print ("\nPlease enter a number between " + str(Lowest) + " and " + str(Highest))
        except ValueError:
            print ("\nPlease enter a valid number")

for Counter in range(1, NoOfRecords + 1):
    Test[Counter] = Temperature ("Mid-Day", 0, 5)

while not Checked:
    for Counter in range(1, NoOfRecords):
        if Test[Counter] > Test[Counter + 1]:
            Test[Counter]
            Test[Counter] = Test[Counter + 1]
            Test[Counter + 1] = Temp

    if Test[1] <= Test[2] <= Test[3] <= Test[4] <= Test[5]:
        Checked = True

print(Test[1], Test[2], Test[3], Test[4], Test[5])
```

But then, using an list...

```
Test = []
NoOfRecords = 5
Checked = False

def Temperature(Day, Lowest, Highest):
    while True:
        try:
            Input = float(input(Day + " Temperature:"))
            if Input >= Lowest and Input <= Highest:
                return Input
            else:
                print("\nPlease enter a number between {0} and {1}".format(Lowest, Highest))
        except ValueError:
            print ("\nPlease enter a valid number")


for i  in range(NoOfRecords):
    Test.append(Temperature ("Mid-Day", 0, 5))


while not Checked:
    for i  in range(NoOfRecords-1):
        if Test[i] > Test[i + 1]:

            Test[i], Test[i+1] = Test[i+1], Test[i]

    if Test[0] <= Test[1] <= Test[2] <= Test[3] <= Test[4]:
        Checked = True

print(Test)
```

Comment: Completely rewritten answer.

Answer (score 1):

this seems simpler and more pythonic. but if your goal was to learn something about sorting this will be no use...

```
Test = []
NoOfRecords = 5


def Tempurature(Day, Lowest, Highest):
    while True:
        try:
            Input = float(input(Day + " Tempurature:"))
            if Highest >= Input >= Lowest:
                return Input
            else:
                print("Please enter a number between {} and {}".format(
                      Lowest, Highest))
        except ValueError as exc:
            print("Please enter a valid number")
            # print(exc)

for Counter in range(NoOfRecords):
    Test.append(float(Tempurature("Mid-Day", 0, 5)))

print(Test)
print(sorted(Test, reverse=True))
```

Comment: It's better to be explicit when catching exceptions (`except ValueError:` in this case), bare `except:` can possibly hide unrelated exceptions.